# Rxjs - remap object with observables as values

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, reactivex, object-properties

I got an observable like this:

```
  const original = Observable.of({
    a: this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/11'),
    b: this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/22'),
    c: this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/33')
  });
```

I need to resolve the inner observables and get something like this in the subscribe handler:

```
  {
    a: ResponseFromServer,
    b: ResponseFromServer,
    c: ResponseFromServer,
  }
```

How should I approach this problem?

Thanks.

EDIT: I've figured it out, read below.

It seems that not many people know that *Map operators used to have something called `resultSelector` as their second argument. Now in rxjs v6, you can do the same with `inner map`, let me show you.

```
const original = Observable.of({
    a: this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/11'),
    b: this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/22'),
    c: this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/33')
});

const transformed = original.pipe(
    mergeMap(sourceValue => 
        forkJoin(_.values(sourceValue)).pipe(map(resolvedHttpRequests => {
            // here you have access to sourceValue as well as resolvedHttpRequests so you can do manual join to match the data.
        }))
    )
)
```

Comment: https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc/blob/master/source/observable/forkJoinObject.ts

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update for 2020**

```
forkJoin(
  // as of RxJS 6.5+ we can use a dictionary of sources
  {
    google: ajax.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users/google'),
    microsoft: ajax.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users/microsoft'),
    users: ajax.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users')
  }
)
  // { google: object, microsoft: object, users: array }
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

Answer (score 1):

They way you're doing it above (with `Observable.of`) is essentially creating a higher-level Observable of lower Observables.

I think a better operator would be [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html), as each of these Observables are cold and finite and `forkJoin` captures the first emission of each Observable and emits all values when all are complete:

```
  const original = forkJoin([
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/11'),
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/22'),
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/33')
  ]);

  let result = {a: null, b: null, c: null};

  original.subscribe([a,b,c] => result = {a,b,c});
```

Just note that the emitted item from `forkJoin` will be an array whose index match the indices of the Observables passed in.

Comment: I needed the data to be observable because it will be processed after this mapping. If you check my edit, you can see how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

If the source object already contains Observables you can do it for example like the following (there are obviously multiple ways to do this):

```
const mockXHRCall = (url: string) => {
  return of('response');
};

const original = of({
  a: mockXHRCall('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/11'),
  b: mockXHRCall('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/22'),
  c: mockXHRCall('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/33')
}).pipe(
  mergeMap(obj => {
    const observables$ = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key].pipe(
      map(response => (
        { [key]: response } // wrap the response with eg. { c: ResponseFromC }
      )),
    ));

    return merge(...observables$);
  }),
  scan((acc, wrapped) => (
    { ...acc, ...wrapped }
  ), {}),
  takeLast(1),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

The `scan` collects all responses and merges them into a single object.

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ffza8b

Comment: Your code would give me some errors on `obj =>` (some kind of bad argument or something). But I already figured it out, check my edit.